# pnpm rebuild package added from git

Tags: dependencies, pnpm

I'm maintaining a large monorepo that relies on pnpm workspaces.

PNPM is v 7.5.0

Some of my packages are using an open source project in which I found some compatibility issues. To overcome this, I forked the project and patched what's missing (also opened a PR to the original repo).

In my repo, I add my dependency not using standard dependency, but as a git dependency

Previously :

```
pnpm add @pnp/spfx-react-control
```

Now :

```
pnpm add "github:stevebeauge/sp-dev-fx-controls-react#features/upgrade-to-spfx-1.15"
```

However, this package is build using webpack. And the emitted javascript files are not part of the sources. This leads to missing module (specifically, `/lib` is missing).

How to trigger rebuilding this package when it comes from a git repo ?

I tried :

```
pnpm rebuild @pnp/spfx-react-control
```

Nothing happens. No error, no `/lib` generated (I guess pnpm try to resolve it as a package within the worspace).

```
pnpm rebuild "github:stevebeauge/sp-dev-fx-controls-react#features/upgrade-to-spfx-1.15"l
```

Failed with :

> `pnpm: Invalid argument - github:stevebeauge/sp-dev-fx-controls-react#features/upgrade-to-spfx-1.15. Rebuild can only select by version or range`

```
pnpm rebuild .\node_modules\@pnp\spfx-controls-react
```

(from my workspace root)

Failed with:

> `pnpm: Invalid argument - .\node_modules\@pnp\spfx-controls-react\. Rebuild can only select by version or range`

```
cd .\node_modules\@pnp\spfx-controls-react\
pnpm run build
```

Failed because of missing dependencies

Comment: This is an interesting question, I've hit this problem at least a couple of times. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The less irritating solution was to git clone the forked repository as a sibling of my monorepo folder, then `pnpm add ../../../my-libfork`. This way I can build separately the lib. The major drawback is that it requires every developer to follow the exact same folder structure and "sync" commits across the repositories. Not very "atomic" operations

Comment: It's a shame we have to use a workaround. I feel like I'm in the minority of people who fork dodgey looking packages, review then install from my github.
I did ind another workaround `"postinstall": "cd /*abs-path*/node_modules/*package-dir* && npm i && npm run build && npm prune --production"`. If you find something else at any point, please let me know.